# How to bind Kendo DropDownList to nested object

Tags: asp.net-core, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-core

Note: this is using the **Kendo UI for .NET Core** package which while similar has differences from the Jquery version so please focus on this platform only.

Initially I had a client dropdown that was bound to `IEnumerable<Client>` returned from Controller and it worked fine:

```cs
 @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
            .Name("ddlClient")
            .DataTextField("ClientName")
            .DataValueField("ClientID")
            .DataSource(source => {
                source.Read(read => {
                    read.Action("GetClient", "Home");
                });
            })           
        )
```

But after restructuring some code I wanted to be able to return an `IEnumerable<ClientViewModel>` from the Controller instead, where `ClientViewModel` would be:

```cs
public class ClientViewModel{
   public Client SelectedClient {get; set;}
   public ClientDivison SelectedClientDivision {get; set;}
   public SomeOtherProperty TheSomeOtherProperty {get; set;}
   //etc
}
```

I modified the dropdownlist to be as follows but it is not working as expected. I verified that the Controller call is still firing and is still returning records as it should be (of type `ClientViewModel`).

Here is the modified DropDownList code

```cs
  @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
            .Name("ddlClient")
            .DataTextField("SelectedClient.ClientName")
            .DataValueField("SelectedClient.ClientID")
            .DataSource(source => {
                source.Read(read => {
                    read.Action("GetClient", "Home");
                });
            })           
        )
```

Also note, I cannot bind this to the main model defined for the view itself since that is a different model altogether, this a standalone dropdown.

I feel like I've referenced nested properties like this before.

What have I got wrong here?

Comment: `it is not working` is a rather broad statement. It does not tell us what is actually happening as apposed to what was expected.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are extremely close: just bear in mind MVC serialises JSON object keys into `camelCase` by default:

this worked for me:

```cs
  @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
            .Name("ddlClient")
            .DataTextField("selectedClient.clientName") // notice casing on both properties
            .DataValueField("selectedClient.clientID") // notice casing on both properties
            .DataSource(source =>
            {
                source.Read(read =>
                {
                    read.Action("GetClient", "Home");
                });
            })
            )
```